# How do you backtrace a class to library/gem it's loaded from?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

If I have a class in Ruby and a Gemfile thousand lines long, what's the best way to resolve the `class => gem` relationship?

Comment: Unless the class has a native implementation, `Klass.method(:initialize).source_location` is probably the best candidate.

Comment: This is actually impossible. Ruby has a concept called "open classes" which means that a class can be defined piece-meal in multiple different files in multiple different gems. In other words, there is no "class definition" (singular) and there is no class → gem relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a `Gemfile` that's *1000 lines long* is probably going to be a big source of pain, especially when upgrading libraries - that's a **huge** list of dependencies!!

It's often obvious which gem is the source, just by looking at the naming conventions. But in cases when not, you can track it down with [`Method#source_location`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-source_location):

```
> puts method(:mystery_method).source_location
> puts MysteryClass.method(:initialize).source_location
```

If you are using `pry`, then there is also a convenient command for displaying the source code of a class/method (using the [`show-method`](https://github.com/pry/pry#code-browsing) command, or `$` for short):

```
(pry) > $ mystery_method
(pry) > $ MysteryClass
```

Also worth mentioning is [`Method#super_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-super_method) - which can be useful when tracking down behaviour from complex inheritance/mixins.

Comment: Thanks though I admit I used 1000 for dramatic effect to help illustrate point